# Unable to drag Element/Item into the Drop Area/Container

Tags: java, selenium, drag-and-drop

**Unable to drag Element/Item into the Drop Area/Container**

**Tech/Softwares used**:

- IDE: Eclipse
- Framework for testing: Selenium
- Language: Java
- Browser: Microsoft Edge - Version 85.0.564.51

**Issue**:

- I'm unable to drag the given Element/Item into the Drop Area/Container (See Images)
- I've also used different Xpaths/Selectors i.e. By-CSS,By-Xpath or By-Class
- It seems that the Element/Item is selected and moved a pixel or two after which the Element/Item freezes and is not dragged to the Drop Area/Container below

**My Attempt**:

- So i've tried different drag and drop functions such as the ones below:-

  ```
    Actions action = new Actions(drv);
    //Source 
    WebElement sourceLocator = drv.findElement(By.className(Item));
   //Destination
    WebElement targetLocator = drv.findElement(By.cssSelector(DropArea));
   //Click -> Hold -> Drag -> Drop
    action.clickAndHold(sourceLocator).moveToElement(targetLocator)
    .release()
    .build()
    .perform();
  ```
- I've also tried using 'dragAndDrop instead of clickAndHold'

  ```
     `action.dragAndDrop(sourceLocator, targetLocator).build().perform();`
  ```

Like I said earlier, The item/element is selected -> Moves a pixel or two then it freezes just above the container (The container pops-up from below as per functionality)

[Green box is the item/element to be dragged and droped - Red box is the area where the item/element should be droped](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U0SCA.png)

[As you can see, the item/element is stuck/frozen right above the drop area](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bFTw4.png)

[Outcome that is expected - Element has been dragged and dropped (Done manually) in the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4hJiH.png)

Comment: Kindly post the website you are trying to automate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try to do it by JavaScript, use the JavaExecutor class from selenium execute the scripts that are in this post, it could work for you

[Why drag and drop is not working in Selenium Webdriver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39436870/why-drag-and-drop-is-not-working-in-selenium-webdriver)

Comment: Thank you!, the answer I was looking for was in the link you've written above