# Unable to move a slider in Firefox 47.0 browser using selenium webdriver and java

Tags: selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver

Unable to move one end of a slider to other end in Firefox browser. But found that the element at one end is clicked but not moved to other end.

Used versions:
Firefox: 46.0 and 47.0
Selenium: 2.53.1

html code before moving the slider:

```
<div class="Slider">
<form name="sliding" action="/sm/performance/slideItem/34912/978310/10445054" method="post">
<div id="moveSlider" style="margin:auto;" data-slide-on="false" data-slide-inactiveicon="url('/sm/resources/styles/common/sliderButton/arrow_button.svg')" data-slide-activeicon="url('/sm/resources/styles/common/sliderButton/move_button.svg')">
<div class="slide-slideWrapper" style="height: 50px; width: 300px;">
<div class="slide-slideButton" style="border-radius: 50px;">
<div class="slide-inner" style="width: 551px; margin-left: -245px;">
<div class="slide-off" style="height: 50px; width: 275px; line-height: 50px;">Slider Moved!</div>
<div class="slide-slider" style="height: 40px; width: 40px; margin-left: -25px; background-image: url(&quot;/sm/resources/styles/common/sliderButton/arrow_button.svg&quot;); background-position: center center; border-radius: 50px; margin-top: 5px;"></div>
<div class="slide-on" style="height: 50px; width: 275px; margin-left: -25px; text-indent: 16.6667px; line-height: 50px;">Move right to slide</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</form>
</div>
```

html code after moving the slider:

```
<div class="Slider">
<form name="sliding" action="/sm/performance/lockBooks/34912/978310/10445054" method="post">
<div id="moveSlider" style="margin:auto;" data-slide-on="false" data-slide-inactiveicon="url('/sm/resources/styles/common/sliderButton/arrow_button.svg')" data-slide-activeicon="url('/sm/resources/styles/common/sliderButton/move_button.svg')">
<div class="slide-slideWrapper"style="height: 50px; width: 300px;">
<div class="slide-slideButton" style="border-radius: 50px;">
<div class="slide-inner" style="width: 551px; margin-left: 0px;">
<div class="slide-off" style="height: 50px; width: 275px; line-height: 50px;">Slider Moved!</div>
<div class="slide-slider" style="height: 40px; width: 40px; margin-left: -25px; background-image: url(&quot;/sm/resources/styles/common/sliderButton/lock_button.svg&quot;); background-position: center center; border-radius: 50px; margin-top: 5px;"></div>
<div class="slide-on active" style="height: 50px; width: 275px; margin-left: -25px; text-indent: 16.6667px; line-height: 50px;">Move right to slide</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</form>
</div>
```

Code we've tried to move the slider:

```
By sliderBar = By.xpath("//div[@id='Slider']//div[contains(text(), 'slider')]");
By slider = By.xpath("//div[@id='Slider']//div[@class='slide-slider'][contains(@style, 'button.svg')]");

WebElement sliderBarEle = driver.findElement(sliderBar);
int sliderWidth = sliderBarEle.getSize().getWidth();

WebElement sliderEle = driver.findElement(slider);
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
action.clickAndHold(sliderEle);
Thread.sleep(3000);
action.moveByOffset(sliderWidth, 0).build().perform();
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors?

Comment: @Sureshmani, No, we didn't got any errors. We saw that code ran completely, but slider didn't moved to other end.

Answer (score 0):

I usually have better luck moving sliders with the `SendKeys` method, and sending either a RightArrow or LeftArrow. I find that with most sliders they respond better to an arrow key press rather than a mouse drag/move. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28453230/selenium-webdriver-move-slider-on-left-side) post on how to do this.

Comment: Manually, the slider is not being moved with Keyboard arrow keys.. The only way to move the slider is by "clicking the slider icon with mouse and dragging it from one end to other end". Could you please help me with other alternatives!!

Thanks in advance!!